# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot - stuck at failed to start clean up any mess left by 0dns-up

Tags: boot

Hi my Ubuntu won't boot and is stuck at

[FAILED] Failed to start clean up any mess left by 0dns-up

As per the answer to this question, I've tried

```
sudo apt-get update || sudo apt-get install -f || sudo apt-get upgrade || sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but it still doesn't work.

[image: Failed to boot]
[image]

The second image is what I got after typing "systemctl status dns-clean.service"